# How to slice an NSArray in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray

What's the simplest way to extract a slice of an NSArray in Objective-C?

(much like the [array_slice](https://www.php.net/array_slice) function in PHP)

Comment: Your first stop should always be the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html in this case).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
-[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]
```

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415157-subarraywithrange